# Relational Algebra, join between 3 tables

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, relational-algebra

I've three tables , employees, purchases and products.
I need to find all the employees who did not sell a product with price > 200 which is mentioned in products table.
Purchases table contains eid referencing employees and pid referencing products.
My relational algebra query is like this, am I right ?

```
 π employees.ename( σ price <> (σ price >= 200(products)) ⨝ (purchases) ⨝ (employees))
```

or

```
π ename(employees) - π employees.ename( σ price >= 200(products) ⨝ (purchases) ⨝ (employees))
```

purchases.pid= products.pid and purchases.eid= employees.eid and ename is from table employees.

Comment: First off, "did not sell a product with price > 500" is absolutely not the same as "did sell a product with price < 500" (or even "price <= 500.")

Comment: yeah,you're right, stupid mistake, let me correct that @DarwinvonCorax

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax can you please check it again? I did some editing.

Comment: Up to the three-way inner join, it looks correct - select all employees who sold a product with price >= 200. However, what you really want is all the *employees* who are *not* in this result set.

Comment: Missed your last edit. Your second expression looks good to me. The first one won't work, though.